# Как импортировать .sql дамп в таблицу?

Tags: mysql, sql, pandas

Прошарил весь интернет (вроде как) и не смог найти решения как можно сделать импорт данных из уже выкачанного SQL дампа в таблицу.

Подскажет может кто?

Comment: Импорт дампа (.SQL) выполняется напрямую. Это текстовый файл с набором SQL-запросов, выполнение которых воссоздаёт структуру и/или данные. Так что просто запустите его через клиент командной строки.

Comment: не, дело не в этом, мне нужно данные из .sql дампа перевести в таблицы pandas

Comment: Сначала их надо загрузить на сервер. Хоть куда-то (по уму - во временно созданную БД). А потом уже распихивать данные в рабочие таблицы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось в общем реализовать обработку SQL дампа без создания БД. Можно было и через создание БД, конечно, но мне было лень поднимать БД, поэтому пришлось искать другое решение:

```
import re
import csv
import sys
import os.path

# помещаем большой текст в dump
csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)

# ищем строку, где начинается дсоздание таблицы в БД
def is_create(line):
    return 'CREATE TABLE' in line or False

def get_table_name(line):
    match = re.search('CREATE TABLE `([0-9_a-zA-Z]+)`', line)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
    else:
        print(line)

# ищем строки, где начинается добавление данных в БД
def is_insert(line):
    return 'INSERT INTO' in line or False


def get_values(line):
    return line.partition(' VALUES ')[2]


def values_sanity_check(values):
    assert values
    assert values[0] == '('
    # Assertions have not been raised
    return True


def parse_values(values):
    rows = []
    latest_row = []
    reader = csv.reader([values], delimiter=',',
                        doublequote=False,
                        escapechar='\\',
                        quotechar="'",
                        strict=True
    )

    for reader_row in reader:
        for column in reader_row[:20]:
            if len(column) == 0 or column == 'NULL':
                latest_row.append(chr(0))
                continue
            if column[0] == "(":
                new_row = False
                if len(latest_row) > 0:
                    if latest_row[-1][-1] == ")":
                        latest_row[-1] = latest_row[-1][:-1]
                        new_row = True
                if new_row:
                    latest_row = ['' if field == '\x00' else field for field in latest_row]

                    rows.append(latest_row)
                    latest_row = []
                if len(latest_row) == 0:
                    column = column[1:]
            latest_row.append(column)
        if latest_row[-1][-2:] == ");":
            latest_row[-1] = latest_row[-1][:-2]
            latest_row = ['' if field == '\x00' else field for field in latest_row]

            rows.append(latest_row)

        return rows


def main(filepath, output_folder):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            try:
                line = line.decode("utf-8")

            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                line = str(line)
            # ищем строки, где начинается добавление в БД
            if is_create(line):
                # ищем название таблицы (оно же будет названием файла)
                table_name = get_table_name(line)
                print(table_name)
                
                # название колонок проставлю просто руками, чтоб не заморачиваться с парсингом
                columns = ['id', 'tdate', 'tname', 'ttext', 'ttype', 'trep', 'trtw', 'tfav', 'tstcount', 'tfoll', 'tfrien', 'listcount']
                print(columns)
            
            
            if is_insert(line):

                # найду место, где начинаются добавляться данные
                values = get_values(line)
                print(values)
                if values_sanity_check(values):
                    rows = parse_values(values)
                    
                # вперед записывать в файл
                if not os.path.isfile(output_folder + table_name + '.csv'):
                    with open(output_folder + table_name + '.csv', 'w') as outcsv:
                        writer = csv.writer(outcsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

                        writer.writerow(columns)
                        for row in rows:
                            writer.writerow(row)
                            
                else:
                    with open(output_folder + table_name + '.csv', 'a') as outcsv:
                        writer = csv.writer(outcsv,  delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                        for row in rows:
                            writer.writerow(row)
```

Это чтобы распарсить свой SQL-дамп и записать csv.

Это решение списал отсюда: https://krypted.com/sql/python-script-to-move-a-sql-database-to-csv-files/

А так как итоговый csv у меня около 3.5 гигабайт получился, то чтобы не было проблем с чтением, то сделал так:

```
!pip install datatable==0.11.0

import datatable as dt 
print(dt.__version__)

%%time

# reading the dataset from raw csv file

train = dt.fread('you_file').to_jay("train.jay")

# reading the dataset from .jay format
train = dt.fread("train.jay")
print(train.shape)

%%time

train = dt.fread("train.jay").to_pandas()
print(train.shape)

train.head()

train.info()
```

Это решение списал отсюда: https://www.h2o.ai/blog/using-pythons-datatable-library-seamlessly-on-kaggle/

Answer (score 4):

Pandas сам не умеет выполнять SQL инструкции - он просто отсылает их на указанный SQL server и уже там происходит вся "магия". Если чуть более подробно, то Pandas использует модуль `sqlalchemy` в качестве посредника для общения с различными БД.

Поэтому самым простым способом будет выполнить SQL скрипт на какой-нибудь БД (как посоветовал @Akina в комментариях) и уже оттуда прочитать данные в pandas.DataFrame, воспользовавшись `pd.read_sql(...)`.

В противном случае вам предстоит титаническая работа по парсингу SQL dump.

Comment: А есть какая-то возможность загнать SQL как временную БД в памяти?

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, а дамп у вас из какой БД?

Comment: а вот хрен его знает ) получил такое тестовое задание и ни разу с такими задачами не сталкивался. беглый гугл ничем не помог и я понял, что задача сложнее

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, ну вы хотя бы первые 5 строчек дампа в вопросе приведите, чтобы было понятно о каком типе БД идет речь... Ну и текст задания неплохо было бы увидеть тоже...

Comment: -- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.12, for osx10.6 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: neu
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.6.12

Comment: Задание: 

Задача для практики такая: в качестве данных используем полный детасет со study.mokoron.com, также нам пригодится тональный словарь rusentilex.

Задача 1: выгрузить в отдельные CSV файлы. Правила по которым выгружаются файлы:

смайлик и слово противоположной тональности к смайлику
содержат по крайней мере два слова противоположной тональности из словаря
с частицами «не» или «ни» и смайлик
со смайликом, но нет оценочных слов
с двумя разными смайликами.

Comment: 3.2гигабайта архив БД

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, и зачем же вам SQL dump если там есть CSV ???

Comment: нет там CSV. есть только SQL дамп. В задаче "выгрузить" означает, что не загрузить себе, а наоборот - из SQL сформировать несколько CSV

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, https://www.dropbox.com/s/fnpq3z4bcnoktiv/positive.csv?dl=0, https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6u59ljhhjdg6j0/negative.csv?dl=0 ???

Comment: вопрос не в этом. ладно ) спасибо, что уделили внимание!

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, я уже ответил на ваш вопрос в своем ответе - если хотите использовать MySQL dump file (кстати вы не указали в вопросе тип БД), то вам придется: 1) поднять экземпляр MySQL БД. 2) импортировать туда данные, загрузив дамп. 3) прочитать данные из MySQL таблицы в pandas.DataFrame.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Пробую использовать такой код:
import sqlite3
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')

with engine.connect() as conn, conn.begin():
    print(pd.read_sql_table('input/db.sql', conn)) 

Ошибка ValueError: Table input/db.sql not found

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, во-первых SQLite БД не полностью совместима с MySQL, во-вторых SQLite не умеет открывать SQL dump файлы - их предназначение только в одном - запустить dump file на целевой БД и получить те объекты БД, которые были экспортированы

Comment: я так понял, что самое верное - это установить БД и дальше к ней приконнектиться.